# Write custom View Resolver to read a JSP from file system and not inside war

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring framework . I am trying to extend any one of the current viewResolver and trying to override the buildView() method to have a custom logic of my own to read a file from file system (on the server) and display it .
   This is a prototype and is investigating on how can i implement it with spring .

Problem i am facing is that i am not able to convert the File to an AbstractView to be returned from buildView .
     Any ideas ?

Comment: It seems not possible with JSP . Will look into a TemplateLoader

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but it does give hints and is too long for a comment.

The problem here is that a JSP needs to be compiled to java file then to a class file to be executed. This is normally done by the servlet container **for files located in the war** (exploded or not). I do not know a public API to do that conversion outside of the web application folder.

Possible hints:

- tie the application to a specific servlet containers and use explicitely methods or tools of that servlet container. I think Tomcat's JSP compiler is documented, and at least as it is free software you can look in the source how to use it.
- forget JSP and use a template solution such as Thymeleaf, Freemarker or Velocity. As there is no compilation phase, it will be much easier and portable. At least Velocity includes a loader that loads files from an absolute folder in file system.